# Java : Memory utilization issue (sudden spike observed)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I was observing memory utilization for my application / service.

I am running the same load and at that time i have seen through Jconsole that memory was ranging between 1.5 to 1.7 GB(can see on image). Suddenly i have noticed that memory goes high for few second but here i would like to mention that nothing has been changed in terms of use case ( same load ).

I need to know that reason of why memory goes up high suddenly.In my setup nothing has changed that cause the reason of memory goes high.

Is there any bug in GC parameters ??

Yours thoughts are requested.

GC parameters I am using is:

> export GC1_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
>   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary" export GC2_OPTS="-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just before the spike a large code is loaded in your system which ensures Atomicity of your application. You need to find it using some good profiling tool. Before that please check if this Occured only once or is occuring more often.

Comment: Can i use profiling in load ( 100 calls).As per my knowledge, i can use profiling in 1 call and in 1 call, everything is running fine.So how to debug ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what it is doing in that period.  Your load may not have changed but you may find that a tasks which normally uses a small amount of memory happens to rarely use a large amount of memory.  I would use a memory profiler on your application to see how memory is being used and which code is causing it.

Comment: Can i use memory profiler in load testing.This issue is visible when i run 100 calls per second.Can i attach profiler in this huge load.I have a doubt.In single call i can use it but then i may not get the reason because in single call everything runs fine.Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: The other processes on the machine can influence your application as well. If some other process suddenly uses more CPU, your application might take a longer time to process its requests, creating more concurrency, hence more memory consumption during that period. You can't expect your memory graphs to be completely regular.

Comment: @Frank - I have added cpu graph as well.CPU does not goes high.It was only approx 25 %...but in graph one lower spike is there.Any thoughts ???

Comment: @VJS The CPU graph is apparently not for the same time frame, but more importantly, that's the CPU graph for *your* application, not for the machine. It might not visibly consume more itself, but still be influenced by its environment because of the small latency introduced. What's notable, though, is that the memory usage stays up after the spike, so if you do a memory dump before such a spike and another after, you'd be able to compare and find the differences in occupation. Also, don't forget that the GC is dynamic and adapts itself to the load, so you may be witnessing such a change.

Comment: @FrankPavageau I agree it could be that under a high consistent load, the you get many small minor GCs, but when you reduce the load the GC increases the size of young generation increasing the maximum sizes and you see a slow consistent (not up and down) increase in usage because a relatively large clean up.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it also depends on the heap parameters, which were not given by the OP; the young generation might be fixed in size (NewSize or Xmn). Moreover, the graphs are obviously the application startup and the following half-hour, so it's still in a dynamic state JVM-wise. But anyway, all we're doing is speculate based on heap and CPU graphs, which is not a lot. I'd suggest using the VisualGC plugin in JVisualVM to gather more information, such as the garbage collections themselves (or use -verbose:gc).

Comment: Actually, I just noticed on the threads graph that there's a small increase at the time of the heap spike, so a small increase of the concurrency is possible. Because of an increase in the requests rate, because a scheduler has triggered some new activity, or even because a concurrency problem finally appeared after some method was compiled by the JIT after its 10000th call and it's now running faster (lock contention).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important part of the question: "What is the problem"
You see that the memory used increases. That could be a bug in your application code that is triggered somehow, but it is not a problem from Garbage Collection point of view.
If you can produce this, I would do two heap dumps, one at 1.7 GB and then one later at 2.5 GB heap.
The you can use Eclipse MAT and the delta mode to compare the dumps. You will see what extra objects you have. Then you can find out if it is a problem or not.

With regards to your GC Settings, I would get rid of "-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" because they usually cause long pause times which are not really needed. Also "-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary" raises the question what your motivation was to use this parameter. I personally would not.